# value out of range entering field in Word footer VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I [previously asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877723/value-out-of-range-error-4608-for-entering-fields-in-footer-using-vba) which went unanswered. I'd like to revive that here, perhaps a bit simpler, and hopefully I can have that question answered.

I need to change the formatting in the footer of over 500 documents and would like to not do it by hand. 
I recorded a macro in an empty document, modified it to clean it up and to not use the selection property: it worked excellently. Once I copy/pasted that block of code into my existing code and I tried it on a document that needs to be changed, I could no longer insert the fields at all and I received a "4608 Value Out of Range" error. If I dimension my `ran1` variable as a `Range`, i get a type mismatch at the definition of the range.
I'd like some help to get the fields actually inserted in the footer.

Below is the code that I am currently working with:

```
Sub EnterFieldInFooter()

Dim wor As Object
Dim fso As Object
Dim fol As Object
Dim fil As Object
Dim doc As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("M:\test")

Dim ran1 As Object

i = 3

Set wor = CreateObject("word.application")

For Each fil In fol.Files

    If Right(fil.Name, 4) = ".doc" Or Right(fil.Name, 5) = ".docx" And Left(fil.Name, 2) <> "~$" Then
        ' open the document
        Set doc = wor.documents.Open(Filename:=fil.Path)

        Set ran1= doc.sections.first.footers(1).Range 'footer range

        ' Set qualifying statement
        ran1.Text = "This is an uncontrolled document when printed or saved. " & _
                    "See online database for most recent version."
        ' Enter the last saved date
        ran1.InsertAfter (vbCrLf & "Save Date: ")
        ran1.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Set ran1 = doc.sections.first.footers(1).Range
        ran1.Fields.Add Range:=ran1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="SAVEDATE \@ ""yyyy/MM/dd""", PreserveFormatting:=True
        ' Enter the last printed date
        Set ran1 = doc.sections.first.footers(1).Range
        ran1.InsertAfter (vbTab & "Print Date: ")
        ran1.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ran1.Fields.Add Range:=ran1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PRINTDATE \@ ""yyyy/MM/dd""", PreserveFormatting:=True

        ' Save updated file
        pat = "M:\test1" & "\" & fil.name
        doc.saveas pat

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you can try `Set ran1 = doc.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryFooterStory)`

Comment: @Slai when I use that, it tells me the requested member of the collection doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you saw may have occurred because you need to supply a section number.  Try this:

```
Set ran1 = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
ran1.Text = "This is an uncontrolled document when printed or saved. " & _
                "See online database for most recent version."
ran1.InsertAfter (vbCrLf & "Save Date: ")
ran1.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
ran1.fields.Add Range:=ran1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="SAVEDATE \@ ""yyyy/MM/dd""", PreserveFormatting:=True
Set ran1 = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
ran1.InsertAfter (vbTab & "Print Date: ")
ran1.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
ran1.fields.Add Range:=ran1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PRINTDATE \@ ""yyyy/MM/dd""", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Depending on your document structure you may need to fiddle with # in Section(#) and with `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` versus `wdHeaderFooterPrimary`.

Hope that helps

Comment: my version of VBA won't let me refer to the footer with the `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` string, I have to use `Sections(1).Footers(1)`, otherwise I receive an error telling me the member of the collection doesn't exist

Comment: Curious what version of VBA you're using. In Tools|References is the reference to `Microsoft Word ##.# Object Library` selected? That's where `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` is defined. Did `Section(1)` help?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I had done so much simple document editing with only the Excel object library enabled without issue that I hadn't considered enabling the Word library. For curiosity's sake, I've been using VBA with Office 2010. Thank you so much for the reminder!